# Optimized sql query to count products in different tables that have reviews from the same user

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have 3 tables, each with reviews of a given type of product,
i.e. reviewshirts,reviewcoats,reviewpants
All tables contain columns for a userid, and an itemid.
Given an itemid in one table, what is an optimized way to query for the combinations of products in other tables that were reviewed by users who reviewed the item with that itemid, grouped by the number of times that combination showed up.

For Example:
given an itemid from the reviewshirts table, 'S11111':

Table reviewshirts:

```
------------------------------
| reviewid | itemid | userid |
------------------------------
|   ???    | S11111 | U1234  |     <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | S11111 | U4321  |     <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | S99999 | U5555  |      (only want userids that reviewed S11111)
------------------------------
```

Table reviewpants:  (find all items that were reviewed by those users)

```
------------------------------
| reviewid | itemid | userid |
------------------------------
|   ???    | P11111 | U1234  |     <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | P11111 | U4321  |     <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | P11111 | U5555  |
------------------------------
|   ???    | P66666 | U4321  |     <---matches
------------------------------
```

Table reviewcoats:

```
------------------------------
| reviewid | itemid | userid |
------------------------------
|   ???    | C11123 | U1234  |    <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | C00024 | U1234  |    <---matches
------------------------------
|   ???    | C00024 | U4321  |    <---matches
------------------------------
```

Returns Result:

```
---------------------------
| pantid | coatid | count |
---------------------------
| P11111 | C11123 | 1     |
---------------------------
| P11111 | C00024 | 2     |
---------------------------
| P66666 | C00024 | 1     |
---------------------------
```

(group results by the number of different combinations of pantids and coatids from users who reviewed S11111)

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Context as requested:
This is for a naive recommendation engine based off previous reviews.

Comment: Are you looking for pairs between pants and coats?  Or, are you looking for combinations with pants and within coats?

Comment: I'm looking for combinations of pants and coats, based off of userids from the shirts table.

Comment: . . That was my understanding, I just wanted to be sure.  Is this for some sort of market basket analysis or recommendation engine?

Comment: exactly.  I didn't collect combination information at the time of reviewing, so I need to go back and do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for pairs of products in the other two tables.  If so, the following query seems to be what you are looking for:

```
select rp.pantid, rc.coatid, count(*) as cnt_pairs,
       count(distinct rs.userid) as cnt_users
from ReviewShirts rs join
     ReviewPants rp
     on rs.userid = rp.userid join
     ReviewCoats rc
     on rs.userid = rc.userid
where rs.itemid = <whatever>
group by rp.pantid, rc.coatid
```

The last column, cnt_users, is the value you want.

This seems like an unusual problem.  Can you edit the question to give some idea how this will be used?